# Why wordpress theme options page not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm tying to install Wordpress theme called North.
The installation is successful, but when I want to access child theme options page, it returns "This page isn’t working".
This is the response :
[image: Theme options page!]

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I dont know that theme but mabye i can help you. What do you mean by "child theme options page"?

Comment: @hashtag-assist
Every theme you purchased, has a parent theme and child theme and we will work on child theme to make customization on a child not on parent .

Comment: Nope, not every theme has a child theme. Do you mean the WP build in theme customizer? Or a theme related options page?

Comment: @hashtag-assist
Sorry, I mean every ecommerce themes have child theme to make your customization on it.
I'm trying now to switch theme to parent, theme options is working but it isn't work on child theme.